# Show active windows/forms open in a menu in Visual Foxpro 9

Tags: menu, visual-foxpro

Working in Visual Foxpro 9, I've been trying to set a menu in wich all running forms are shown in a menu, in a style of the menu "Window" of Foxpro itself.

Using the Menu Designer Wizard, I've been able, so far, to add a "Cycle" item by inserting a menu bar with the option set to "_mwi_rotat"

Is there any way to accomplish this feature? I've been googling it to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the built-in Window pad in the menu. That's easy to do if you create your menu with the Menu Designer and start with a quick menu. Then just remove what you don't want and add what you do, but leave the Window pad and the Cycle item.

Comment: Sorry if I seem to be oblivious, but in the Menu Designer where do you start with a quick menu? Whenever I start a new one, there's nothing but an empty row, like this image: [link](http://flylib.com/books/2/920/1/html/2/afd11001.gif)

Comment: Choose Menu | Quick Menu from the menu.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer.